# How to return values in multiple columns based on conditions in another dataframe column python

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement

I have a main dataframe say DF1 with column values, Category, Subcategory, Group, Text. I need to validate if correct category and subcategory is against each group and text columns.

I have another dataframe say DF2 with same 4 columns and the expected category and subcategory for group and keywords to be available in text column.

DF1:

| Category | Subcategory | Group | Text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sweet | Cake | G6 | mandatory for birthdays and weddings |
| chocolate | DairyMilk | G1 | Packed in blue, dark and white combo |
| Chips | Lays | G2 | Multicolor wraps, different flavors |
| Chips | Bingo | G3 | Triangle shape & has multiple flavor |
| chocolate | DairyMilk | G5 | Blue wrapper |

DF2:

| Category | Subcategory | Group | Text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sweet | Cake | G6 |  |
| chocolate | DairyMilk | G1,G5 | blue, dark and white |
| Chips | Bingo | G3 | Triangle, flavors |
| Chips | Lays | G2 | Multicolor , flavors |

I need to add predicted category and subcategory in DF1 based on DF2 values. Example if
Condition1:

```
DF1['Group'] is G6 , DF1['predictedCategory']=='Sweet' and DF1['predictedSubcategory'] == 'Cake'
```

Condition2:

```
DF1['Group'] is G1 or G5 and DF1['Text'] contains blue or dark and white, DF1['predictedCategory']=='chocolate' and DF1['predictedSubcategory'] == 'DairyMilk'.
```

I tried writing if else statement with multiple conditions but it returns empty in predicted columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
for index, item in df1.iterrows():
for i in range (0,l):
    if   ((item['Group'] in df2.iloc[i,2]) & pd.isnull(df2['Text'].iloc[i])):
        val = df2.iloc[i,0]
    elif ((item['Group'] in df2.iloc[i,2])):
        if df2.iloc[i][3] != '':
            list = df2.iloc[i][3].split(',')
            for elem in list:
                if(elem in item['Text']):
                    val = df2.iloc[i,0]
df1.at[index,'Predicted'] = val
```